# Facebook Like, Image association

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating Facebook Like button in my site, I want to be able to present a specialized Image for my page, I have setup all the  tags appropriately, however, while developing, I am working in LAN, and thus, [facebook **scraper**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)  is not able to remotely access my page.

Having the above mentioned in mind, is there any way of testing facebook like integration w/o a public IP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Graph tags only work if Facebook can reach them - so they MUST be available in public. One way would be to start a server on your computer and use port forwarding on your router so Facebook can access your server. But it would be way easier to just upload your code somewhere. There are plenty of free providers (OpenShift, Heroku, ...) but i assume you will need a "real" server sooner or later anyway.